# How to install perfmon2 on ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, software-installation, software-recommendation

i want to install performer counter on Ubuntu. http://sourceforge.net/p/perfmon2/libpfm4/ci/master/tree/
this source has all the steps, as i am the new user, every time i try to implement the steps, error occurs.

Comment: *"every time i try to implement the steps, error occurs"* this doesn't tell us much: what steps? what error? If you are new, you should probably be using the pre-built libpfm4 package from the Ubuntu repository - unless you have a **really** good reason to install a different version.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and follow the commands below:

1. Install `git`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git
   ```
2. Clone the repository

   ```
   cd
   git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/perfmon2/libpfm4 perfmon2-libpfm4
   ```
3. Start the compiler in `perfmon2-libpfm4`

   ```
   cd perfmon2-libpfm4
   make
   ```
4. Install

   **You have three options, choose one**

   1. Install with `make`, the standard way

      ```
      sudo make install
      ```
   2. Create a package with `debuild` and install with `dpkg`

      ```
      sudo apt-get install dpatch swig
      debuild -i -us -uc -b
      sudo dpkg -i ../libpfm4_6.0_amd64.deb
      sudo dpkg -i ../python-libpfm4_6.0_amd64.deb
      ```

      and if you want the development packages

      ```
      sudo dpkg -i ../libpfm4-dev_6.0_amd64.deb
      ```
   3. Create a package and install with `checkinstall`

      ```
      sudo apt-get install checkinstall
      sudo checkinstall
      ```

Comment: The readme says it supports building proper Debian packages as well.

Comment: @muru Thx, improved